# Monoogse create method isn't creating anything

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create a new document in my API via an ajax request.

Here's my code:

```
mongoose.model("Meals").create(
    {
        _id:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(),
        id:id,
        createdBy:basicAuth(req).name,
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        tags: tags,
        mealAdded:(new Date).getTime(),
        mealModified:(new Date).getTime(),
        ordersLog:[]
    },
    function (error,out) {
        res.send("Server responded with: " + out);
    }
);
```

So according to the [documentations](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) this should work. But for some reason the `out` is `undefined` and the `error` is just an empty object `{}`.

Here's my model:

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var mealsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     _id:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     id:{type:String},
     createdBy:{type:String},
     title: {type:String},
     description: {type:String},
     tags:[{type:String}],
     mealAdded:{type:Number},
     mealModified:{type:Number},
     ordersLog:[{
         number:{type:Number},
         epoch:{type:Number},
         phoneNumber:{type:String},
         Address:{type:Number},
         paid:{type:Number},
      }]
 });
 mongoose.model('Meals', mealsSchema);
```

I've checked the `meals` collection, and nothing is really added!

I don't know what I'm missing, I'm lost.

Comment: You don't need to define `_id` on the Schema. Mongoose adds it  for you. You also don't need to generate that _id on create. Mongo will do it for you. In addition, Mongoose aliases `._id` as `.id`, so defining it as a field in your Schema will open you up for potential side effects. If you want a secondary id field, I'd name it explicitly `mealId`. That being said, your issue is that you're using `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` vs `new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()` to generate your objectId.

Comment: Have you issued `mongoose.connect()` anywhere in your code? Odds are on that you have not.

Comment: @cdbajorin thanks, that really solved my problem. It's weird that it wasn't giving me any errors though.

Answer (score 0):

I test your code under `Mongoose v4.4.3`, Error is shown as below

> [Error: document must have an _id before saving]

It seems incorrect `objectId` is generated through `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId()`, refer to this [`ObjectId`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_MongooseThenable-Types)
and change code as below, it works well.

```
var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
var id = new ObjectId;
console.log(id);
Meal.create(
    {
        _id: id,
        id: '123',
        createdBy:'abc',
        title: 'dddd',
        description: 'youare',
        tags: 'asdfg',
        mealAdded:(new Date).getTime(),
        mealModified:(new Date).getTime(),
        ordersLog:[]
    },
    function (error,out) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log("Server responded with: " + out);
    }
);
```